# C++ string expansion leads to allocation errors

Tags: c++, string, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a [memory leaking library](http://left404.com/leaker/) to check my application for memory leaks. However, a very simple program is already causing memory leaks.

Consider the following program assigning 14 characters to string Message:

```
string Message;
int main() {
    Message = "This is a test";
    }
```

Leads to no memory errors.

However, when I try to initialize string Message with a length of more than 15 characters (let's say 20) it gives me a memory leakage error:

```
string Message;
int main() {
    Message = "This is a test which";
    }
```

Leads to the error:

```
Leaks found: 1 allocations (31 bytes)
```

Apperently, c++ is allocating 16 bytes of space if you initialize a string like (which leads to max 15 characters + \0):

```
string Message;
```

However, if I initialize message as:

```
string Message = "This is a test which is long enough to hold 'This is a test which'";
```

The previous memory leakage error is gone.

So, C++ is not allocation memory nicely when I try to work with dynamic string-size that overflows the size of the actual declaration of the string buffer?

To visualize:

```
string Message; //Allocates 16 bytes of memory whereof the 16th position is \0
Message = "This is a test which"; //longer then 15 --> Memory Leak
```

However, if I do the following it is not producing any errors:

```
string Message = "This is a test which can hold a long string";
Message = "This is a test which"; //NO ERRORS
```

How can I overcome this issue in C++? I prefer to stick with the usage of strings, however I need to know how to expand a string correctly. Thus, let C++ handle the memory allocation if the string content is overflowing the previously allocated memory.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.  So it seems this is either (a) a bug in your leak detector, (b) a bug in your C++ implementation (unlikely), or (c) a false positive.

Comment: The `std::string` class implementation might use different schemes to allocate memory for the strings depending on its length. And if the leak-detector doesn't handle global variable destruction properly it can report false positives.

Comment: So, how is it possible that the memory pool used by the application keeps growing if I would loop the assigning of a string to the message variable?

Comment: Looks like your leak detector just doesn't work. Nevertheless, the differences it does observe are likely due to Small-String Optimisation (SSO) in your compiler's `std::string` implementation.

Comment: By the way... *"Unlike newer languages like Java and C#, C and C++ don’t automagically manage your memory for you."* - That sentence alone should give you an idea of how professional and reliable the tool is.

Comment: In general, you should not expect version 0.1 of anything to be particularly good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `leaker.h` header tries to intercept memory allocations by adding a set of `#defines`:

```
/* preprocessor magic to override built-in allocation functions with our own */
#define malloc(size)        _malloc(size, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__)
#define calloc(n, size)     _calloc(n, size, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__)
#define free(ptr)           _free(ptr, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__)
#define realloc(ptr, size)  _realloc(ptr, size, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

#ifdef __cplusplus

/* hackish solution to the problem of overriding C++ operator new/delete */
extern const char *_leaker_file;
extern const char *_leaker_func;
extern unsigned long _leaker_line;

#define new (_leaker_file=__FILE__, _leaker_func=__func__, \
    _leaker_line=__LINE__) && 0 ? NULL : new
#define delete _leaker_file=__FILE__, _leaker_func=__func__, \
    _leaker_line=__LINE__, delete
```

If we forget about redefining keywords like `new` and `delete` being explicitly not allowed, this hack only has a chance to work if every part of the `std::string` implementation is defined as inline functions.

If some parts of `std::string` are implemented in the runtime library (not unlikely), these defines will not have any effect on the precompiled code there. And then the detection will only be partial and miss some allocations or deallocations.

Answer (score 3):

Message is a global variable.

Your leak detector must be taking a snapshot of memory state after the global variable is constructed, but before main is started.

Then taking a look at memory after main ends, but before global variables are destructed.

The std::string often (but not always -- implementation dependent) has an implementation optimization for short strings... but strings longer than that are allocated on the heap.

Your leak detector is seeing the string on the heap, not realizing Message destructor which will be called shortly will release that back to the heap in short order.